# How to call Python code (including third-party modules imported) from C++?

Tags: python, c++

I'm developing a program on Windows using Visual Studio, and trying to call some simple python code from C++.

I've tried cython, e.g. my `.pyx` file looks like this:

```py
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

cdef public tf(input):
    f = interp1d(..., list(input), kind='cubic')
    im = f(...)
    tf = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((112, 112)), ...)])
    return tf(im)
```

and cythonize it via `cython xxx.pyx` or write a `python setup.py`.

After adding the generated file and python dependencies my project, it was fine in linking and compiling, but when running, **symbols from third-party module `__pyx_n_s_interp1d` would failed in the `__Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName()` function, and it seems that the modules imported isn't included in the generated `.c` file.**

So, the problem is how to call python code **(including functions from third-party modules)** from C++ via Cython or other utils like pythran, pybind11, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I use Python in a project that is build on a different language (most of the time c#) is compile the python code via `pyinstaller --onefile script_path`, start the compiled script from a new process with `Name_of_executable some args` and read the stdout value when it has finished. I don't know whats the equivalent of starting a new process in c++, but in c# you can use System.Diagnostics.Process. Pyinstaller includes all modules and imports in the executable and I know that is not best practice, but it works usually.

Edit:
you can install pyinstaller via `pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: Creating a new process in C++ is platform dependent. In Linux you can fork() and then execve.
On Windows you can use CreateProcess() in processthreadsapi.h